# How to make xdotool type Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, xdotool

I'm trying to make a shortcut to send, for example, the universal quantifier symbol, ∀ (U+2200). Xdotool's [own documentation](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#keyboard_commands) doesn't really explain this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the above symbol, there are two options:

1. Xdotool generates the character and types it:

   ```
   xdotool key U2200
   ```
2. The shell (Bash) generates the character, and Xdotool types it:

   ```
   xdotool type $'\u2200'
   ```

Comment: Also `ctrl+shift+u` then `2200` will input a unicode symbol. Or in [KDE set a compose sequence](https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey) to do it.

Comment: @pbhj How would you do that in Xdotool though?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is:

```
echo -n "${TEXT}"|xsel -b

xdotool key ctrl+v
```

This fills the mouse buffer, then pastes it.

Comment: Why not just `xdotool type "$TEXT"`? And how do you generate the Unicode character in the first place? It's usually a good idea to avoid non-ASCII text in source code.

Comment: Minor thing, but avoid using `echo` on arbitrary text; use `printf '%s'` instead. If for example, `TEXT='-e'`, you won't get anything printed since `-e` is a flag to `echo` and there's no way to escape it properly.