# xdotool : inserting unicode "by hand": i.e NOT "key U " but "ctrl+shift+u"

Tags: unicode, xdotool

I've got a Russian keyboard layout. This one doesn't have the acute sign which is used for stress mark in academic field.

I can do that by hand. After a character, for example, и:

ctrl+shift+u 301 space --> и́

I'm trying to use xdotool to make a shortcut to insert this stress:

I've already tried to use the same solution in [How to make xdotool type Unicode characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591686/how-to-make-xdotool-type-unicode-characters), but for some reason, the acute sign is special (it's not a character by itself, it's adding itself to the previous one) and it's not working.

So, I want xdotool to type for me all the sequence `ctrl+shift+u 301 space` that I'm typing by hand.

What I've done is now:

```
sleep 0.2 &&
  xdotool key --delay 15 'ctrl+shift+u' &&
  sleep 0.2 &&
  xdotool type 301 &&
  xdotool key space
```

But when doing that, xdotool stops at "U", waiting for me to fill in the number

Answer (score 2):

U+301 is the **combining** acute accent (that is, it gets added onto the previous character). You want the **non-combining** acute accent, U+B4:

```
xdotool key UB4
```

There's also a sub-optimal solution, which is to have xdotool send the combining acute accent and a space, but it only renders properly in some programs:

```
xdotool key U301 space
```

Also, beside the point, but your code worked perfectly fine on my machine. I'm not sure why it didn't on yours.

Answer (score 0):

These are old questions but I'll share my experience in case it helps someone.

I found that the xdotool solutions were unreliable, and because its driving a C library that is ASCII only there were limited options for solving the problem.

In the end I used Linuxes ability to display and store unicode characters to store them on the clipboard. Xdotool is used to paste them into the active window.  So the code is:

```
echo 'λ' | xclip -selection clipboard;  # save unicode char(s) on clipboard
sleep 0.5; 
xdotool key 'ctrl+shift+v';  # paste to active window
sleep 0.3;  
xdotool key ctrl+h  # backspace because I was getting an extra linefeed
```

I checked with xsel --clipboard and it also worked.

Comment: Why not just use `xdotool type λ`?