# Enter Unicode mathematical symbols conveniently

Tags: unicode, unicode-entry

I want to conveniently enter Unicode symbols such as greek letters μ, ξ, ... and mathematical symbols such as ∀, ∃, ...

Using the character map is not convenient.

I would prefer to enter something like \delta and have it converted to δ by pressing TAB or any other key similar to many LaTeX editors.

The background is, that I want to use eclipse for editing Julia code. But being able to do this with the operating system is better than making eclipse do that.

Autokey-gtk seems to do what I want. But I cant get it to run. Crashes each time an event is triggered.

Comment: If you use Atom, there is https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-latex-completions.

Comment: It should be possible to replace the unicode number in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` with the latex command.  (One day I'm going to try.)

Comment: Not sure, but I guess the events in that file are all like this one: <Multi_key> <U11BC> <U11A8>. So Composite key and exactly 2 other keys.

Comment: If you want to set up something with `xdotool`, [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/q/591686/301745) could be useful

Comment: @Kalle With the Compose key, you press Compose, then other keys in sequence, not at the same time.

Comment: You know about `ctrl+shift+u+UNICODE`, eg `UNICODE=03B4` will give `δ`. IME, unfortunately, for shortcuts for unicode entry it matters what WM you're using and which apps you want to enter the data in to: might want to look at `xim` and maybe at `ibus-setup` (used to set the control sequence for entering unicode code points). Using AltGr/Compose is also handy.

Comment: in [KDE you can set a compose sequence](https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey) to enter any unicode symbol

Comment: Not sure if this will help but Texlipse is a Latex editor for Eclipse https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/science.texlipse

Answer (score 4):

If you use Visual Studio Code, install `latex-input` extension.

It works as following:

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty! Maybe worth a try. However, I do not really want to switch IDE for this.

Comment: looks nice, but in the case your language has repl (python/haskell), it is also nice to have the same in the terminal

Comment: nice way to demonstrate it!